# Not enough space to update

Tags: apt, upgrade, disk-usage

I'm getting the following error when running pretty much every `apt-get` command:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-3.13.0-153-generic : Depends: linux-headers-3.13.0-153 but it is not going to be installed
```

I do not have enough space to run `apt-get -f install` (or `-f autoremove`) as suggested:

```
Unpacking linux-headers-3.13.0-153 (3.13.0-153.203) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-153_3.13.0-153.203_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-153/include/linux/lapb.h.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-153/include/linux/lapb.h'): No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-3.13.0-153_3.13.0-153.203_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

And I cannot remove/purge `linux-headers-3.13.0-153-generic` because `linux-headers-generic` depends on it. Even though I'm botting from another version:

```
$ uname -r
3.13.0-141-generic
```

So, I'm pretty much stuck here. I've seen other questions like this but answers are usually to remove/purge old kernels. I **cannot purge/remove old kernels** as it gives an error like in the first snippet.

- How can I remove 3.13.0-153 related packages?
- Is there an alternative way to safely remove packages to free up space?

---

**Edit**

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G  4,0K  7,8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  1,4M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb7        24G  2,2G   21G  10% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            7,8G   46M  7,8G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb5       454M  299M  128M  71% /boot
/dev/sdb6       7,3G  6,0G  898M  88% /usr
/dev/sdb2       296M   70M  227M  24% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       3,7G 1006M  2,5G  29% /var
/dev/sda5       118G   83G   30G  74% /home
$
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-106                              3.13.0-106.153                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-115                              3.13.0-115.162                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-123                              3.13.0-123.172                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-125                              3.13.0-125.174                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-128                              3.13.0-128.177                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-128-generic                      3.13.0-128.177                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-129                              3.13.0-129.178                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-129-generic                      3.13.0-129.178                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-132                              3.13.0-132.181                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-132-generic                      3.13.0-132.181                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-133                              3.13.0-133.182                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-133-generic                      3.13.0-133.182                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-135                              3.13.0-135.184                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-135-generic                      3.13.0-135.184                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-137                              3.13.0-137.186                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-137-generic                      3.13.0-137.186                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-139                              3.13.0-139.188                                      all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-139-generic                      3.13.0-139.188                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-headers-3.13.0-153-generic                      3.13.0-153.203                                      amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-95                               3.13.0-95.142                                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-96                               3.13.0-96.143                                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-98                               3.13.0-98.145                                       all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 3.13.0
ii  linux-headers-3.13.0-98-generic                       3.13.0-98.145                                       amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-headers-generic                                 3.13.0.153.163                                      amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
$
$ ls /boot
abi-3.13.0-128-generic     config-3.13.0-129-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-128-generic  memtest86+.elf                 System.map-3.13.0-141-generic          vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic
abi-3.13.0-129-generic     config-3.13.0-132-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-129-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin       System.map-3.13.0-153-generic          vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic.efi.signed
abi-3.13.0-132-generic     config-3.13.0-133-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-132-generic  retpoline-3.13.0-153-generic   vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic             vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic
abi-3.13.0-133-generic     config-3.13.0-135-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-133-generic  System.map-3.13.0-128-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic.efi.signed  vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic.efi.signed
abi-3.13.0-135-generic     config-3.13.0-137-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-135-generic  System.map-3.13.0-129-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-129-generic             vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
abi-3.13.0-137-generic     config-3.13.0-139-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-137-generic  System.map-3.13.0-132-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-129-generic.efi.signed  vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic.efi.signed
abi-3.13.0-139-generic     config-3.13.0-141-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic  System.map-3.13.0-133-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-132-generic             vmlinuz-3.13.0-141-generic
abi-3.13.0-141-generic     config-3.13.0-153-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-141-generic  System.map-3.13.0-135-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-132-generic.efi.signed  vmlinuz-3.13.0-141-generic.efi.signed
abi-3.13.0-153-generic     efi                        lost+found                     System.map-3.13.0-137-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-133-generic             vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
config-3.13.0-128-generic  grub                       memtest86+.bin                 System.map-3.13.0-139-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-133-generic.efi.signed
$
$ ls /boot/ -1hs
total 290M
1,2M abi-3.13.0-128-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-129-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-132-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-133-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-135-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-137-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-139-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-141-generic
1,2M abi-3.13.0-153-generic
163K config-3.13.0-128-generic
163K config-3.13.0-129-generic
163K config-3.13.0-132-generic
163K config-3.13.0-133-generic
163K config-3.13.0-135-generic
163K config-3.13.0-137-generic
163K config-3.13.0-139-generic
163K config-3.13.0-141-generic
163K config-3.13.0-153-generic
4,0K efi
1,0K grub
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-128-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-129-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-132-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-133-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-135-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-137-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-139-generic
 20M initrd.img-3.13.0-141-generic
 12K lost+found
173K memtest86+.bin
174K memtest86+.elf
175K memtest86+_multiboot.bin
1,0K retpoline-3.13.0-153-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-128-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-129-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-132-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-133-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-135-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-137-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-139-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-141-generic
3,3M System.map-3.13.0-153-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-128-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-129-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-129-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-132-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-132-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-133-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-133-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-135-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-139-generic.efi.signed
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-141-generic
5,6M vmlinuz-3.13.0-141-generic.efi.signed
5,7M vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
$
$ du -s -h /usr/*
344M  /usr/bin
520K  /usr/games
25M  /usr/include
1,9G  /usr/lib
467M  /usr/local
du: cannot read directory ‘/usr/lost+found’: Permission denied
16K  /usr/lost+found
25M  /usr/sbin
2,0G  /usr/share
1,4G  /usr/src
```

---

**Edit**

Problem seems to be related to inode capacity in `/usr`:

```
$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           2041123     604 2040519    1% /dev
tmpfs          2043915     678 2043237    1% /run
/dev/sdb7      1581056   49149 1531907    4% /
none           2043915      11 2043904    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none           2043915       3 2043912    1% /run/lock
none           2043915     147 2043768    1% /run/shm
none           2043915      28 2043887    1% /run/user
/dev/sdb6       488640  484619    4021  100% /usr
/dev/sdb5       122400     342  122058    1% /boot
/dev/sda3       244320   33951  210369   14% /var
/dev/sda5      7839744 2857681 4982063   37% /home
/dev/sdb2            0       0       0     - /boot/efi
```

However, most answers for freeing up space rely on `apt-get`. This is not an option here because of the problems stated above, and so I need another safe way to clear some space in `/usr`.

Hopefully this will allow `apt-get -f install` to add all missing dependencies.

Comment: You can start with `sudo apt-get clean`. Also please add output of `df -h` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert `clean` doesn't seem to do anything. I've updated the question with the results of `df -h`.

Comment: As we need to determine where free space is needed - in */boot* and */usr* please add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-headers`, `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`, `ls /boot`, `ls /boot/ -1hs`, `du -s -h /usr/*`  to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert ready.

When I started this thread, `df -h` was returning a 100% use for `/usr`. Not sure what happened there.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get autoremove`?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't work. First two code snippets are the outputs for `autoremove` without `-f` flag and with it, respectively.

Comment: I have no more ideas. See possible duplicate post for solutions.